# Entity Framework 6 update a table and insert into foreign key related tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Not quiet sure how to word the title for this one so feel free to edit if it isn't accurate.

Using an example, what I am trying to accomplish is update a record in table foo, and then create new records in a subsequent table that has the foo tables PK as foreign key, think One-to-Many relationship.

How do I update a table that has foreign key constraints and create a new related record(s) in these subsequent table(s)?

Currently I am using Entity Framework 6 to .Add and .Attach entities to the context and save them to the database.

*Edit*

To clarify further what I am trying to achieve, the below object is a cut down made up example what I am trying to save to the context. If I try to .Add intObj after "Billy Bob" has already been created because he has bought a new car, another service, or his tyres have changed it will create a new Billy Bob record (duplicate) and the corresponding related tables.

```
        intObj.FirstName = "Billy";
        intObj.Lastname = "Bob";
        intObj.Important = 100;
        intObj.LastSeen = DateTime.Now.Date;
        intObj.Cars = new List<Car>{
            new Car{
                Model = "Commodore",
                Make = "Holden",
                YearMade = DateTime.Today.Date,
                Odometer = 15000,
                EmailWordCount = 500,
                TyreStatuss = new List<TyreStatus>{
                    new TyreStatus{
                        Tyre1 = "Good",
                        Tyre2 = "Good",
                        Tyre3 = "Okay",
                        Tyre4 = "Okay"
                        }                                 
                },
                Services = new List<Service>{
                    new Service{
                        Cost = "$500",
                        Time = "2 Days",
                        Date = DateTime.Today
                    }
                },
            }
        };
```

Thanks

Comment: What approach are you using. Code first? Model/Database first?

Comment: I am using code first @E-Bat

Comment: I elaborated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following snippets you have Employee class, which references two more entities: a collection of Assignment and a single Country.
 
ORMs like EF , NHibernate, etc...  have a feature known as Transitive Persistence, that is, if an object (Assignment and Country) is referenced by a persistent one (Employee), then Assignments and Country will eventually become persistent too when, in your EF case, SaveChanges method gets invoked in the Context, without you explicitly save them.

```
    public class Employee
        {
            public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
            public virtual string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
            public virtual Country BirthCountry { get; set; }
            private ICollection<Assignment> _assignment = new List<Assignment>();
            public virtual ICollection<Assignment> Assignments
            {
                get
                {
                    return _assignment;
                }

                set
                {
                    _assignment= value;
                }
            }
        }

        public class Assignment
        {
            public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
            public virtual DateTime BeginTime { get; set; }
            public virtual DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
            public virtual string Description{ get; set; } 
        }

        public class Country
        {
            public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
            public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        }

   //Somewhere in your program      
   private void SaveAllChanges()
         {
             _db = new EFContext();
             //Creating a new employee here, but it can be one loaded from db
             var emp = new Employee { FirstName = "Emp Name", 
                 LastName = "Emp Last", EmployeeNumber = "XO1500"
             };
             emp.BirthCountry = new Country { Name = "Country1" };
             emp.Assignment.Add(new Assignment{ BeginTime = DateTime.Now,EndTime=DateTime.Now.AddHours(1) });

            //Only employee is explicitly added to the context
            _db.Employees.Add(emp); 
            //All the objects in the employee graph will be saved (inserted in this case) in the db. 
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

That is very similar to my code above, once "Billy Bob" is created you only need to update it, and that include any new service he buy;

Pseudo code:

```
var bob = _db.Clients.SingleOrDefault(c=> c.Id = "Bob Row Id")
//Bob buy a car:
bob.Cars.Add(new Car()...)
//...and change tire 1 from an old car
var car = bob.Cars.SingleOrDefault(c=> c.Id = "Car Row Id")
car.TireStatus.Tire1 = "New"
....

//Persist all changes
//Existing objects will be updated..., and the new ones created in this process will be inserted
_db.SaveChanges()
```

Let me know if this clarify your ideas

Comment: Thanks for the reply @E-Bat. That is the approach that I tried initially. I have updated my question to include some more detail, let me know if my query requires more clarification

Comment: Awesome thanks mate that fills the gap, working correctly now!